# How to export to csv a gatling log file

Tags: csv, google-sheets, gatling

I am trying to export a gatling log file to CSV as i need to updated all the global values in google spread sheet as my manager needs it in a spread sheet.

Comment: They have inbuilt feature to export results in csv , see this discussion https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/593

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This CSV file is dropped and replaced by a JSON one, named `global_stats.json` located in the `js` directory. CSV wasn't suited for this.

Comment: Thanks stephane. This solves a lot of our issues for a report generation.Your a savior